# Display user feedback without marquee / javascript / jquery

Tags: html, css, marquee

I want to display some feedback (max 80 words in four lines) on a website; 
Here maximum i can use 20% height of the screen (with 100% horizontal width)

Currently, I'm using code mentioned below:

```
<marquee scrollamount="1" behavior="scroll" direction="up" height="20%" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
    ABCD<br/>
    Sample Text<br/><br/> 
    XYZ<br/>
    New Sample Text<br/>
</marquee>
```

Today i read marquee is depreciated tag and there are many options to achieve similar effect using jQuery.

I've one more constraint ; to NOT use any jQuery / javascript on the page. 
Is there any good suggestion to display user feedback keeping in mind points mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve a marquee effect using purely CSS

### [Demo Fiddle (Horizontal)](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/XxUXD/1204/) ([Vertical](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/h7SYp/653/))

HTML

```
<p class="marquee">text text text text text</p>
```

CSS

```
.marquee {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 4s linear infinite;
}
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        text-indent: 27.5em
    }
    100% {
        text-indent: -10em
    }
}
```